# What Oracle SQL syntax do I need to find transactions that occurred during time intervals of a day for a period of a year?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am looking at a transactional-level table for which I need to extract all transactions which occurred between certain hours (between 15:00 and 23:59) of a day for the past year.  How can I do this using Oracle SQL syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a WHERE-condition like this:

```
WHERE datecol BETWEEN DATE '2014-01-01' AND DATE '2014-12-31' 
  AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST(datecol AS TIMESTAMP(0))) BETWEEN 15 AND 23
```

To dynamically define the previous year:

```
WHERE datecol >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, 'year'), -12) -- jan 1st previous year
  AND datecol < TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, 'year')                   -- jan 1st current year
  AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CAST(datecol AS TIMESTAMP(0))) BETWEEN 15 AND 23
```

Comment: SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM SALESDETAIL
WHERE CREADATE BETWEEN DATE '2014-10-12' AND DATE '2015-10-12' AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CREADATE) BETWEEN 15 AND 23;

The following gave me ORA-30076: invalid extract field for extract source.  The CREADATE column has a DATE type assigned to it.

Comment: @weaponG: Sorry, Oracle doesn't allow `EXTRACT` on `DATE` columns, only on `TIMESTAMP`
, fixed it.